# Django - How can I prevent access to other users' objects?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

Let's assume that I have such URL `users/{id}/objects` and I am authenticated as a User with ID equals 1. At the moment I can access objects of users with ID equals 2, 3 etc. Does anyone have an idea how can I prevent this?

```
class UserObject(GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = [UserPermission]
    def get(self, request, user_id):

            try:
                object = Object.objects.filter(user=user_id)
            except Object.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)


class UserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            return True
        return False
```

I tried in this way:

```
serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

def get_queryset(self):
    return Object.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

def get(self, request, user_id):

        try:
            object = Object.objects.filter(user=user_id)
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: in the template check if the id == request.user.id

Comment: In the view, rather.

Comment: @mohammedqudah I tried it with if `user_id == self.request.user.id:` but it doesn't work. Maybe it is possible to check it in `GetPermission` Class?

Comment: It is -- should other users have read access to these objects? if not 
        `if request.method =='GET' or (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser):` should simply be `        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser:
`

Comment: also note `is_superuser` is just a function right now. I would remove this all together unless the object may only be accessed by a super user. If you mean the owner *and* the super users should be able to access the object, this should be an `or` and I believe you must call `is_superuser()`

Comment: may be you have already seen it if not go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053122/controlling-django-auth-user-access-to-specific-object-instances)

Comment: I am sorry I added wrong Permission Class. I updated my question.

Comment: @VincentBuscarello No, only owner can access the objects. At the moment it is only required to be a user and to be authenticated and you can access all objects of different users. I want to make it possible to have access to only own objects.

Comment: Can you add a print statement to has_permissions to see if its being called at all?

Comment: ```if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            return True```

will always return true if anyone is authenticated. it should look more like (not sure, approximating) `view.instance.user == request.user`

point is, we need to access the objects user and compare it to the requests user. I think we can hack into the view some how and do this, but if we are using the right view type we can call "has object permission" -- be sure and read up on this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Comment: @VincentBuscarello I added `print("test")` below `def has_permission(self, request, view):` and after sending `users/1/objects` there is printed `test`

Comment: @VincentBuscarello can you show how it should be done on this GenericApiView?

Answer (score 4):

If you overload the view's `get_queryset` to only return objects belonging to the current user then Django will handle the appropriate errors and responses on its own.  For example,

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.MySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

See also http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes

Comment: It doesn't work. I added my code to the updated question. Maybe I have done something wrong?

Comment: It could be not working for any number of reasons, like that you don't have the right authentication classes.  Or that `owner` is not how `Portfolio`s are linked to `User`s.  There's nothing magical about the word `owner` -- you have to change the example filter to fit your own relational situation.

Comment: Also, if you are doing it in this way, you probably don't need to overload `get` --  the whole point is that you can accomplish your goal with just this and don't need to overload `get` for every view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IsAuthenticated` permission only to check if someone is logged in and than check "manually" if the user is asking for data of its own or not. Like this:

```
class UserObject(GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, user_id):

        if (str(reques.user.id) != user_id):
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        try:
            object = Object.objects.filter(user=user_id)
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you really want to use a custom permission your can leave you view untouched and make you permission classe like this:

```
class UserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (not request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return False

        user_id = request.path.split('/')[1]

        if (str(request.user.id) == user_id):
            return True

        return False
```

Note: I'd recomend the first option.

Note: this code is an example, if it doen't work right away, try to 
understand the idea and adapt it. I didn't tested it and it may need some ajusts, specially the part that gets the `user_id` frorm `response.path`.

Comment: But maybe it is possible to add it to UserPermission Class? I will have quite a lot of GenericViews to modify if I use your solution.

Comment: I think you can do it, although it's a little trickier. You'll need to access `user_id` from the `has_permission` function inside your custom permission class. Since the `request` object is an [extension](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#standard-httprequest-attributes) of `HttpRequest`, which [has](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) a `path` field, you can extract the `user_id` from there and compare it with `request.user.id` and make it work without touching your views.

Comment: Can you show me how it could be done on `class UserPermission`?

Comment: Edited the answer to do it.

Comment: Just change 1 for 2

Comment: Yes, I know but even if I have both `request.user.id` equals 1 and `user_id` equals 1 I get  `"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."`

Comment: It returns False at the bottom of `has_permission `

Comment: There should be `if (str(request.user.id) == str(user_id)):` Now it seems to be working properly.

Comment: Why do you recommend first method?

Comment: I think the drawback of this method is that for instance for URL `users/sth/{id}/sth2` It will not be working, am I right?

Comment: Exactly, it's fragile to strip the `user_id` from `path` since it can change.

I recommend you change your views and make the check as the first snippet of my answer.